# LL grammar with associativity and self referring productions

Tags: parsing, antlr, operator-precedence, ll-grammar, associativity

I am trying to write a parser grammar and currently have the following productions for an LL Grammar (in Antlr) and I am trying to parse one or more (numbers or strings) that is separated by a "#" that is right associative. How do I modify the the productions so that it can parse one or more strings separated by "#" instead of just one at the moment?

```
A ::= B
    | Number
    | String

B ::= C "->" A

C ::= Number
    | String
```

Examples of languages for this grammar:

```
ABC # 123
123 # ABC
ABC # DEF # 123
ABC # DEF # (123 # 456)
ABC # (DEF # 123) # 456
```

I tried using the EBNF form

```
A ::= B
    | Number
    | String
    | "(" A ")"

B ::= C ("#" A)?

C ::= Number
    | String
```

But that causes my Grammar to be ambiguous. How would I fix this ambiguity?

Comment: `A::=(A)` is unlikely to be correct, even if you actually wrote `A::="("A")"`. The parenthesized expression is a primary (`C` in your grammar).

Comment: How would I have parse something like ABC # (DEF # 123) if my parenthesized expression is C?

Answer (score 0):

The ambiguity comes from the fact you can derive `Number` or `String` two ways -- either directly `A` -> `Number`, or `A` -> `B` -> `C` -> `Number` (and similarly for `String`).  The obvious fix is to get rid of the direct productions:

```
A ::= B
    | "(" A ")"

B ::= C ("#" A)?

C ::= Number
    | String
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is quite a bit simpler:

```
A ::= B ( "#" B )*
B ::= Number | String | "(" A ")"
```

Not being an ANTLR pro, I'm not sure how you would go about marking `#` as right-associative, but the intent of the rule is to produce a list of `B`s, so you could presumably associate them to the right in the semantic rule.

It's important to put the parenthesized expression rule at the bottom of the hierarchy (so to speak); otherwise, you wouldn't be able to parse `( first # second ) # third`.